# Mysql WHERE clause or php IF condition?

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

I often have to check a table column before performing an update, insert, or delete in mysql. I'm wondering if this is redundant because the mysql `WHERE` clause is already a condition.

**Example:**

- A database table named `private_messages` stores private messages for
  users.
- A column named `read` has a default value of `0` and updates to `1`
  when a user has read a message.

**Which one of the two methods is most efficient and accurate for updating the table?**

Perform a query, return the value of `read`, and use an `if` condition:

```
if (read == 0) //if user did not read message
{
   UPDATE private_messages
   SET read = 1
   WHERE id = 48 //the unique, auto increment index
}
```

Or simply add a `WHERE AND` clause to the query:

```
UPDATE private_messages
SET read = 1
WHERE id = 48
AND read = 0
```

and use `mysql_affected_rows()` to determine if a row was updated.

**Edit:** Another situation could be deleting a row if a column has a certain value. Should I use `if` condition or `where`?

Comment: In any case, the `AND read = 0`part of the second query seems irrelevant. With regard to the additional question I suggest this also should depend on the availability of the read variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you alread have the `read` variable in memory (ie, queried for other purposes), I would choose the first method, as if the message is not read, you won't need to query the database.

If you don't have the `read` variable in memory, use the second method, has it will only query the DB one time.

Comment: May I propose to never use the second version but simply drop the if condition, if `read`is not already in memory, since in the php manual it is stated, that `When using UPDATE, MySQL will not update columns where the new value is the same as the old value. This creates the possibility that mysql_affected_rows() may not actually equal the number of rows matched, only the number of rows that were literally affected by the query. ` so as Arjan proposed there is no need to `AND read = 0`

Answer (score 4):

I believe MySQL checks whether the new value you're trying to insert is the same as the existing value, and only performs the write operation if they are different.  So no need for the IF statement.

Comment: I think the OP inserts the if to know what happened in the first version, whilst a subsequent call to mysql_affected_rows() will yield the same info in the second version.

Comment: Dilettant is right. The statements should also return a message if nothing was affected.

Answer (score 3):

The first options makes two queries to the database. The second only one. There is your answer.

Comment: True but the goal is not entirely about speed. (edited question)

Comment: Really? I understood, that in the second version, there are always two queries: 1 updating 2 counting affected rows

Answer (score 1):

The second option appears to be more efficient, because it requires only a single round-trip to the server. However, benchmarking is the only way to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need either. You can simply update the row (based on id) without checking for the current value of `read`. It still guarantees that after the query has been executed, the value of `read` is 1.

```
UPDATE private_messages
SET read = 1
WHERE id = 48
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Makes 1 or 2 db queries.
2) Always makes 2 db queries because of the mysql_affected_rows() part.

Comment: Are you sure that `mysql_affected_rows()` does another query to the BD ? or is it stored in the `link_identifier/resource` as a result of the `UPDATE` ?

Comment: I thought so but after reading up on the function I'm not certain anymore.